# MacOS: How to fix error PIP installing with python 3.7.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I´m getting the next error when I try to install pip on MacOS Mojave

I tried to solve it using

```sh
$ brew install python
```

but it doesn´t work

```sh
$ python --version
```

Python 3.7.4

```sh
$ sudo python get-pip.py
```

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: That seems very off to me.  Python 3 in Homebrew comes with ssl support for sure.  And I'm pretty sure it comes with a version of pip installed too.  Though they're called python3 and pip3.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that pip is already installed, if the Homebrew installation of python was successful.

[The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/) notes that when installing Python through Homebrew, "Homebrew [automatically] installs pip pointing to the Homebrew’d Python 3 for you."

Try running `which pip` or `which pip3`. If you get a response of `/usr/local/bin/pip` or `/usr/local/bin/pip3`, then Homebrew installed pip already for you. Else try `brew unlink python3 && brew link python3`.

And for clarity, from the aformentioned guide:

> `$ python` will launch the Homebrew-installed Python 3 interpreter.
>
> `$ python2` will launch the Homebrew-installed Python 2 interpreter (if any).
>
> `$ python3` will launch the Homebrew-installed Python 3 interpreter.

As far as I know, `pip`, `pip2`, and `pip3` will do the same.